# How to copy EMR streaming job logs to S3 and clean logs on EMR core node's disk

Tags: logging, streaming, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

Good day,

I am running a Flink (v1.7.1) streaming job on AWS EMR 5.20, and I would like to have all task_managers and job_manager's logs of my job in S3. Logback is used as recommended by the Flink team.
As it is a long-running job, I want the logs to be:

1. Copied to S3 periodically
2. Rolling either on time or size or both (as there might be a huge amount of logs)
3. Get cleaned from the internal disk of the EMR nodes (otherwise the disks will become full)

What I have tried are:

1. Enabled logging to S3 when creating the EMR cluster
2. Configured yarn rolling logs with: *yarn.log-aggregation-enable, yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir, yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds, **yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds***
3. Configured rolling logs in logback.xml:

```
    <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.file}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>30MB</maxFileSize>    
            <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>50MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{60} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

What I got/observed until now are:

- (1) did help with periodically copying the logs file to S3
- (2) seemed useless for me until now. Logs are only aggregated when the streaming job ended, and no rolling was observed.
- (3) yielded some result, but not close to requirements yet:

  - the rolling logs are there in some cache folder (*/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1549236419773_0002/container_1549236419773_0002_01_000002*)
  - only the last rolling logs file is available in the usual YARN logs folder (*/mnt/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1549236419773_0002/container_1549236419773_0002_01_000002*)
  - only the last rolling logs file is available in S3

In short, out of the 3 requirements I got, I could only either (1) or (2&3).

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks and best regards,

Averell

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the auto-backup of logs to S3 that EMR supports will only work at the end of the job, since it's based on the background log-loader that was originally implemented by AWS for batch jobs. Maybe there's a way to get it to work for rolling logs, I just have never heard about it.

I haven't tried this myself, but if I had to then I'd probably try the following:

1. Mount S3 on your EC2 instances via `S3fs`.
2. Set up `logrotate` (or equivalent) to automatically copy and clean up the log files.

You can use a bootstrap action to automatically set up all of the above.

If `S3fs` gives you problems, then you can do a bit more scripting and directly use the `aws s3` command to sync logs, and then remove them once they've been copied.

Comment: Thank you @kkrugler. As per this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html, logs in EMR are copied to S3 every 5 minutes. But it seems that only some specific folders are monitored. I am looking for a configuration place to change this.

Will try your suggested solution as well.

Comment: @Averell Did u find a solution? I'm in the same spot.

Comment: @JackTuck: I haven't. Will update the post if I have found one.

Comment: @Averell I have setup cloudwatch in the interim. It does the trick. But is not ideal i just have config which looks at logs files from all yarn node/resource managers, taskmanagers, jobmanagers. And set TTL to 1 day.